# How do I pass initial props (or launchoptions) to first scene?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am sending data from Android Native to React native by setting a simple prop in Android via the `launchoptions`.

I was successfully able to receive the initial props in the react-native module, but now when I am using `StackNavigator` like this :

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    { 
        home: Details,
        genre: Genre,
    },
    { 
        initialRouteName: 'home',
    }
);
const AwesomeProject = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default AwesomeProject;
```

Now I am unable to use my `Prop` in the HomeScreen's constructor. How do I pass my initial props into the `home` screen?

The react-native version I am using is **0.58.4**

Here's the full **Code in React-Native** :

```
import { 
  createStackNavigator, 
  createAppContainer 
} from 'react-navigation';

import Genre from './app/Genre';
import Details from './app/Details';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    { 
        home: Details,
        genre: Genre,
    },
    { 
        initialRouteName: 'home',
    }
);

const AwesomeProject = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default AwesomeProject;
```

Here's the **Android code**:

```
@Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                String str = MainActivity.getMovieID();
                bundle.putString("movie_id", str);
                return bundle;
            }
        };
    }
```

My problem is exactly same as this one:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/634

But the problem is the solution given by the user is for an older version of react and in the new `react-navigation-3` you must set up your app container directly, so his solution does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got it to work and was successfully able to send `initialProps` from native android to react-native's first scene of `StackNavigator` like this:

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    { 
        home:  {screen: Details},
        genre: {screen: Genre},
    },
    { 
        initialRouteName: 'home',
    }
);

const RootStack = createAppContainer(StackNavigator)

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
    return <RootStack screenProps={this.props.movie_id} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According the document, you can define [params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#params) to your routes

Comment: `home: {
   screen: Details,
   params: {screenProps: this.props.movie_id}
  },`  Do you mean like this ?

Comment: Yes, That's right. In addition, You can get screenProps value from navigationOptions

Comment: sorry but this is showing an error: **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.movie_id')**

Comment: with this I can send _any_ param to scenes in react-navigation but the main problem is I don't want to send just _any_ param, I want to send the props from **AwesomeProject** which is not accessible in params.

Comment: See this:   https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/634